# Finding a solution to this second order constant coefficient differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{(4)}-16y''+40y'-25y=0$, which yields

$r^4-16r^2+40r-25=0$, so I just graphed it, and it gave me $r=-5,1$, but it does not give me $r=2+i$ or $r=2-i$. How do I find these, and also, how does one find the solution to this?

Comment: have u guessed a solution which is a divisor of the constant term and did some division?

Comment: Divide $r^4-16r^2+40r-25$ by $(r+5)(r-1)$ to get the other roots after using the quadratic formula. As for the final solution, do you want just real solutions or complex solutions included?

Comment: Just real solutions

Comment: Wait, I know how. But if you post a solution, I'll accept the answer since you helped me find the 2+i, 2-i

Comment: Wait, ... how do you factor that ?

Comment: Apply rational root test.

Comment: @Nameless I used the quadratic formula for r^2-4r+5, but I'm not getting 2+i, 2-i...

Comment: @MathStackExchange, show your work?

Comment: Wait, yeah I am, nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is given by
$$y(x)\to c_3 e^{-5 x}+c_4 e^x+c_1 e^{2 x} \sin (x)+c_2 e^{2 x} \cos
   (x)$$
you cam up with $$(r-1) (r+5) \left(r^2-4 r+5\right)$$

Comment: Can you show how you arrived at this answer please? How did you factor, how did you divide, etc?

Comment: Okay, but how exactly do I factor it into that? I just graphed it before....I honestly forget how.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you have a complex eigenvalue $\alpha+ i\beta$, you'll have a solution: $$y(t) = e^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t) + e^{\alpha t}\sin(\beta t)$$

Find the complex roots of the polynomial to get these real solutions. *How* to find the roots boils down to algebraic techniques, such as using Girard relations, the rational roots test, inspection, etc.

Comment: I can't remember if I haven't learned eigenvalues...... I don't want complex solutions, just the real ones

Comment: The solutions to the ODE are not complex ones. They are real. Finding the *complex* roots of the characteristic polynomial is nothing more then a step to finding the **real** solutions to the ODE.